# Applying styles to only selected element, without affecting children elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

This is fairly simple, so I'm sure I'm just missing something obvious.

Say I have this example code:

```
<main>
    <header>Header</header>
    <section>
        Content
    </section>
    <section>
        Content
    </section>
    <section>
        Content
    </section>
</main>
```

And initial CSS of:

```
main{text-align:center;}
section{display:inline-block;width:33%;}
```

So I have three columns taking up more or less a third of the page each. Now, because of the way the code is written, there will be white space on the page. My preferred method of dealing with this is to set `*{font-size:small}`, and then add `body>main{font-size:0;}`.

Of course, thats fine on a simple page, where the font is the same. However, with different sized fonts and header tags here and there, this doesn't work well.

I think I just misunderstood what it is that the `>` selector does, but what I'm trying to look for is a selector that styles an element, without applying said style to children elements. In this case, I want to style my main element, but I don't want the style affecting the header or section elements.

What is the right way to do this?

And before anyone suggests it, no, I do not wish to use the other methods for removing white space (HTML comments, moving the final part of the closing tag onto the next line, etc.), as they look ugly and I prefer my code to look as presentable as my page.

Comment: You're not misunderstanding the `>` selector. The problem lies with inheritance. Some properties are inherited by descendants of an element, even if you ensure you only apply a property to that element using `>`. The solution to your problem depends on the inheritable property that's being used.

Comment: Well, because of how I want to remove white space between my elements, I'm setting the font-size property. My only issue is what happened to the header elements h1 to h6. I want them to keep their default font sizes, but they inherit the property from the parent element. I currently set font-size to small on *, but then this makes h1 to h6 the same size as everything else.

Answer (score 0):

First off: I'm not exactly sure if this works and not able to thoroughly test right now. This should have been a comment but I'm lacking the reputation to do so. sorry.

The problem is that the font size is one of the properties that is inheritet from it's parent and values like "small" don't set absolute sizes, but relative to the inherited size. so I would try to reset the size right after your main layer, using an absolute value instead of a relative one

```
body>main>*{font-size:18px;}
```

The important part is obviously not using a relative size, however, I have no idea how this holds up to user-specified default font-sizes. also, you would have to ensure that any text that has a non-medium font-size (so in your case any and all text) is at the very least a grandchild of main since the font-size for all direct children will be overwritten.

hope this will help you; bw

Comment: I'm afraid it still doesn't solve the problem of losing the default h1-h6 sizes. Otherwise, I could have just used a font-size of 'small' for *, and 0 for body>main. It's that pesky inheritance problem that I can't get around.

Comment: You've already overwritten all default font-sizes with '*{font-size:small}'. You could try adding the :not() selector, however, support for several exceptions ( :not(h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6) ) is far from stable. General consensus is, not to select by * but instead to use a comma-separated list of all the elements that you want to style (whitelisting as opposed to blacklisting). This will also make sure that you don't accidentally style elements when when you add new types in the future.